# IBM JMS MQ adding userID in MQM header

Tags: java, tomcat, ibm-mq

How do I set userID in MQM header in IBM JMS MQ, default it will be 'mqm' I need to set it to different userID while sending the message. I am using com.ibm.mqjms jar and the application is deployed on Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

In your application you need to access some IBM MQ features that are outside of the JMS specification.

IBM MQ v8 Knowledge center documents how to set MQMD properties with IBM MQ Classes for JMS  in the page "[Reading and writing the message descriptor from an IBM MQ classes for JMS application](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032330_.htm)"

> You must set the Destination object property WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED to true for the setting of MQMD properties to have any effect. You can then use the property setting methods of the message (for example setStringProperty) to assign values to the MQMD fields. All MQMD fields are exposed except StrucId and Version; BackoutCount can be read but not written to.
>
> This example results in a message being put to a queue or topic with MQMD.UserIdentifier set to "JoeBloggs".
>       // Create a ConnectionFactory, connection, session, producer, message
>       // ...
>
> ```
> // Create a destination
> // ...
>
> // Enable MQMD write
> dest.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED, true);
>
> // Optionally, set a message context if applicable for this MD field
> dest.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_MESSAGE_CONTEXT, 
>   WMQConstants.WMQ_MDCTX_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT);
>
> // On the message, set property to provide custom UserId
> msg.setStringProperty("JMS_IBM_MQMD_UserIdentifier", "JoeBloggs");
>
> // Send the message
> // ...
> ```

---

In order to use `WMQ_MDCTX_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT` you will need to grant the user that connects to the IBM MQ queue manager the `OAM` permission `+setid` on both the `qmgr` object and on the `queue` where the messages will be `PUT` to in addition to any normal permissions that you would grant (ex: `+connect +dsp` on the `qmgr` or `+put` on the `queue`).